# AView and its associated ViewModel are not deallocated when navigating back in SwiftUI NavigationView

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a SwiftUI app with a NavigationView and a NavigationLink that pushes a AView onto the navigation stack. The AView has an associated AViewModel that is created using @StateObject. When navigating back from AView, I expect the view and its associated ViewModel to be deallocated, but I notice that the ViewModel's deinit() method is never called. This leads to a memory leak and increased memory usage over time. How can I ensure that AViewModel and AView are properly deallocated when navigating back in the navigation stack? Here is the code:

```
final class AViewModel: ObservableObject {
    deinit {
        print(">>> AViewModel deinit  \(self)")
    }
    
    init() {
        print(">>> AViewModel init \(self)")
    }
}

struct AView: View {
    @StateObject private var viewModel = AViewModel()
    var body: some View {
        Text(">>>")
            .onDisappear {
                print(">>> AView disappear")
            }
            .onAppear {
                print(">>> AView appear")
            }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink(destination: {
                AView()
            }, label: {
                Text("AView")
            })
        }
    }
}
```

I have asked the ChatGPT, but it cannot solve the problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=Swiftui%20viewmodel%20deinit&searchOn=3

Comment: state object is not designed for view model objects you have to learn the View struct

Answer (score 2):

You have just to add '.navigationViewStyle(.stack)' modifier to NavigationView or use a NavigationStack instead.

Solution 1:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink(destination: {
                AView()
            }, label: {
                Text("AView")
            })
        }
        .navigationViewStyle(.stack)
    }
}
```

Solution 2:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            NavigationLink(destination: {
                AView()
            }, label: {
                Text("AView")
            })
        }
    }
}
```

It works in both ways.

Comment: It works. But why add `.navigationViewStyle(.stack)` can solve this problem?

Comment: @ParisMeta Because when you adopt a Stack navigation Style you're using a Navigation Model very similar to the one used by UINavigationController in UIKit.

So when you perform the pop action, the view at the top will be destroyed and with it all its dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

NavigationView's "automatic" setting is column, which you might see if you support landscape orientations on an iPhone Pro Max. Once you "navigate" to a particular child, that child view remains in the second column until another child is selected.

At that point in time you'll see the previous child's VM deinit.

You see the same behavior in portrait orientation because iOS doesn't know whether or not it might get flipped to landscape and need to show the child once more.

Which is why the .stack style works. It kills that behavior.